# How to write a paginator for ArrayList in java

Tags: java

In my project, I want to show a paginator. I have 100 employee Objects in my ArrayList, now I want to show on every page only 10 objects (means 10 employee's information). On a click on next, I want to show the next 10 records.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your output format (Swing app, web app)? This is not a site for getting free code.

Comment: An `ArrayList` is not the most elegant solution for this, since you cannot query a range of entries. However, if you have to, you could use the `ArrayList.get(index)` method to query elements by index.

Comment: If you're retrieving this employee information from a database, then query to the database according to the current page size of your choice instead of retrieving the whole result set from the database and then retrieving a sublist from that result set and storing the sublist into an `ArrayList`. That you can't do, if your database has a number of rows.

Comment: Thanks for the replay .In my project i want to fetch the googlegroups members.so when i pass this url https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/group/2.0/soharcoas.com/1s1s1s1s/member i got all members form the group now i want to show the members in pagenation format every page i want to show 15 members .i am using java and google app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic principle of a pagination system:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int pageNumber = *X*;

    // list containing numbers from 1 to 100
    final List<Integer> list = populatedList();
    final int RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 10;

    // algorithm
    int to = pageNumber * RESULTS_PER_PAGE;
    int from = to - RESULTS_PER_PAGE;
    for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}

public static List<Integer> populatedList() {
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    return list;
}
```

For example, with `pageNumber = 2`, you'll get the following output:

```
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Comment: I think, sorting of the `List` is essential while implementing the concept of pagination (either in ascending or descending order, depending upon the requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Which technology?
Do you are developing web or desktop application?
If you are using web application with JSF you can use primefaces table pager: 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf
It is very easy.